# Options not getting added again when the form is submitted +zendFramework

Tags: php, zend-framework, jquery, combobox, zend-form

i have to dependent combo box

```
 $this->addElement('Select', 'Category',array(
         'label'      => 'Category:',
         'AutoComplete'=> true,              
         'multiOptions' => array('0' => '-Category-',$a->GetCategories(),'2' => '-Add             category-'),
         'required' => true ));

  $this->addElement('Select', 'SubCategory',array(
          'label'      => 'Sub Category:',
          'AutoComplete'=> true, 
          //'multiOptions' => array('0' => '-Select Category-'),
          'required' => true ));
```

the second one is filled using ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  //for send data i'll use jquery library
  $(document).ready( function(){
    $('#Category').change(function() {
      var message=$('#Category option:selected').text();
      if (message != '') {
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          dataType : 'json',
          url: 'http://localhost/EverTags1/Authentification1/public/Product/add', 
          async: false,
          data:{"message" : message}, 
          success: function (respond) {
            var json=JSON.stringify(respond);
            var  objet = eval('(' + json + ')');
            e=objet.length;
            var str = "";
            for ( var count = 0 ; count < e; count++ ) { 
              str += "<option value='" + count + "'>" + objet[count].name+ "</option>"
            } 
            $("#SubCategory").empty().append(""+str);
          }
        }); 
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

The elements were loaded correctly in the second combobox. But when I submitted the content of the second combobox disappears. how can i make them displayed

Answer (score 1):

you need to update multioptions after each ajax request. i used session to do that

```
public function getsubcategoriesAction()
{
   if($this->_request->isXmlHttpRequest())
    {
        $session = new Zend_Session_Namespace('mySession');
        $this->getRequest()->param('id',1)
        $model = new Application_Model_DbTable_Subcategory();
        $result = $model->getSubcategories($category);
        // save the result to session
        $session->result = $result;
        $this->_helper->json($result);

    }
}
```

and in the action that render the form

```
 public function createAction()
 { 
    //some code here

    if($this->getRequest()->isPost()){
        $session = new Zend_Session_Namespace('mySession');
        $subCategory = $form->getelement('subCategory');
        $subCategory->addMultiOptions($session->result); // get the result back from session

      //some code here
   }
}
```

you need also to enable sessions in you application.ini

```
 resources.session.save_path = APPLICATION_PATH "/../data/session"
 resources.session.use_only_cookies = true
 resources.session.remember_me_seconds = 864000
```

Answer (score 0):

Does adding the  `selected='selected'` attribute to the first option of #SubCategory fix it?